# iframe/lightbox refresh issues

Tags: javascript, iframe

Please check out: http://gherkin.co.nz/refresh/ and click on the purple box that says 'Membership chest'

You should then see some form fields in an iframe in the lightbox.

If you click on the "GO" button, the page will change (currently Not found, which is fine for now). If you click the dark area to close the box, then click the purple card again - it will take you back to the not found page. When called, I want the content to always go back to the page specified in the iframe src, not the last page.

Can it go back to the first specified page on this second click?

Does that make sense? basically I want the iframe/lightbox to refresh its content each time it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fr = document.getElementById('iframe1'); fr.src = fr.getAttribute("src")` before calling the lightbox on your onclick element.

Comment: Thanks Javier, sorry to sound like a fool, but where do I put this line of code? In the <script> before function ShowLightBox() ? or within the link?

Comment: oh no, it's been a long day/night - I just read your answer again, did what you said and it works perfectly. THANK YOU SO MUCH!